# p:chart bar's ChartSeries not synchronized

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, bar-chart, jqplot

I've been working on PrimeFaces Bar chart model,and its getting on my nerves now,I just can't get how its setting chart series values.What expected result should be that One Open for say abc and one closed for xyz, But what It shows one open and one closed for xyz,ABC is Ignored. If I change the position of

`barModel.addSeries(close);
 barModel.addSeries(open);`

to

`barModel.addSeries(open);
barModel.addSeries(close);`

Then It shows One open and one closed for only abc,Not xyz.

here's my **getBarModel()** first,

```
public BarChartModel getBarModel() {

barModel=new BarChartModel();

     ChartSeries open = new ChartSeries();
     open.setLabel("OPEN");
     ChartSeries close = new ChartSeries();
     close.setLabel("Close");
 open.set("abc", 1);
     close.set("xyz", 1);

     barModel.addSeries(close);
     barModel.addSeries(open);





        barModel.setMouseoverHighlight(false);
        barModel.setShowPointLabels(false);
        barModel.setTitle("Incident_application");
        barModel.setLegendPosition("ne");
        barModel.setShowDatatip(false);
        barModel.setShowPointLabels(true);
        barModel.setExtender("chartExtender");
        barModel.setSeriesColors("A2CC39,1B75BA");
        Axis xAxis = barModel.getAxis(AxisType.X);
        xAxis.setLabel("Applications");
        barModel.setAnimate(true);
        Axis yAxis = barModel.getAxis(AxisType.Y);
        yAxis.setLabel("No. of Incident");
        yAxis.setMin(0);
        yAxis.setMax(20);
        yAxis.setTickInterval("10");  

        return barModel;
}
```

and here is **xhtml**

```
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" target="head" />
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery-plugins.js" target="head" />

<style type="text/css">

table.jqplot-table-legend {
border: none;
font-size: x-large;
}
div.jqplot-table-legend-swatch 
{
width: 2vw;
height: 2vh;
}
div.jqplot-gridData{
display:none;
}
div.jqplot-xaxis-tick{
font-weight:bold !important;
}
.jqplot-axis.jqplot-xaxis{
font-weight:bold;
}
.jqplot-point-label {
font-size: 300%;
color: black;
font-weight: bold;
}
.jqplot-target{
color:black !important;
}

</style>    
<script> 

function chartExtender() {        

this.cfg.grid = {             
background: 'transparent',
gridLineColor: '#303030',
drawBorder: false,
};


}
</script>
<h:form id="barChart">


<p:chart id="bar" type="bar"  model="#{incidentBarChartController.barModel}"  />


<p:poll interval="10" global="false"  update="barChart"/>

</h:form>

</h:body>
```

Snapshots of expected and Actual results are added below.

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCX0l.png)

[Actual Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXpb6.png)

**Edit**
After adding

```
open.set("abc", 1);
         open.set("xyz",0);
         close.set("xyz", 1);
         close.set("abc", 0);
```

I still get weird results i.e.
1 open and 1 closed for xyz and 0 open and 0 closed for xyz.

Comment: You need to give each set/series a value for each key. So also add  `open.set("xyz", 0);close.set("abc", 0);` (maybe 'null'  works to). Or maybe this needs to be configured on the jqplot level via the extender

Comment: This is going to be too complex because of dynamic data.

Comment: Why? Are the key's 'ordered' in one way or another? Or is the order relavant? Combining the keys in one set in the correct order is the only 'challenge'. And then adding then looping though that set and adding the  missing ones in the other sets should not be to difficult. PF or jqPlot cannot solve that for you. They cannot know which of the two sets contains the right order. Suppose set 1 starts with "a$#" and set 2 starts with "a#$", which one should come first? Ordered according to "String" But what if for you "xyz" should come before "abc"?

Comment: If I try to do this open.set("abc", 1); open.set("xyz",0); close.set("xyz", 1); close.set("abc", 0); BarChart shows weird results,Please check check edits

Comment: It is a `LinkedHashMap` (check the source), so the order is relevant. Set them in the same order in both sets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution is that you as a developer make sure all series contains all keys and populate the keys which you do not have and make sure all keys in all series are in the same order.

The reason for this is that only you know the real order (that is why a `LinkedHashMap` is used in the series). jQplot or PrimeFaces cannot know this. If e.g. the first series misses a key and that series is used as the 'primary' to iterate over, where is the missing key going to put. And if e.g. at position 6, both have a key that is not in the other set, which one should be taken first? The jqPlot or PrimeFaces cannot know. All reasons that you as a developer should make sure it is explicit by putting all keys in all series.

Comment: Well Exactly,This has to be the only  case.I'll give it a try and be back .